# How to rename any component in a flow developed using Oracle Integration Cloud Service (ICS)?

Tags: oracle, integration, soa, osb, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've developed a simple flow in Oracle Integration Cloud Service (ICS) release 13. But there is no option to rename or delete any components that are being added to the flow.below is the screenshot

[image: ics flow]

In the above flow trying to rename the 'AccountCreateEvent' but didn't find any option for that.

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer

If you are using Integration Cloud Service or Oracle Integration Cloud there is no functionality in the web interface that lets you change the name of an adapter inside an integration. Those names are merely for documentation purposes and do not provide any functional value beyond readability and convention. However, if you are like me you value convention and readability.

### Longer Answer

There is a way to change the name by exporting or downloading the OSB artifact.  I will outline how to do this manually, then give a brief description of how to do this a more appropriate way (with some background information as to what ICS actually is underneath the covers).  Additionally, if you don't get any responses from Stack Overflow, Oracle has a very active [Customer Cloud Connect](https://cloudcustomerconnect.oracle.com) forum, and you can also place an [SR](https://support.oracle.com)

#### 1. Manually

You can manually update the name by modifying the underline XML of an export project.  First export your project as seenn below [image: export image]

Exporting will download a file with an `iar` extension.  This is a a compressed file, so untar the file (or open it with 7z, winrar, etc). You should see the following directory structures

```
|-- icspackage
   |-- appinstance
   |-- project
      |-- the_name_of_your_project
         |-- PROJECT-INF
            |-- layout.json
            |-- project.xml
         |-- resources
         |-- ics_project_attributes.properties
```

> I am only showing you the pertinent directory tree here.  There is obviously more nodes but they are not pertinent.

Open your project.xml file.  Here is a sample file with a single REST app adapter with no HTTP response body, no invocations, no actions, and no transformations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:icsproject xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/flow/definition" xmlns:ns1="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/project" xmlns:ns0="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ics/project/definition" name="project_1" version="7.3" modelType="freeform">
    <ns0:projectCode>LEAD</ns0:projectCode>
    <ns0:projectVersion>01.00.0000</ns0:projectVersion>
    <ns0:projectName>Lead</ns0:projectName>
    <ns0:percentComplete>0</ns0:percentComplete>
    <ns0:projectHasErrors>true</ns0:projectHasErrors>
    <ns0:projectHasWarnings>false</ns0:projectHasWarnings>
    <ns1:icsflow name="flow_1">
        <application name="application_8">
            <role>source</role>
            <adapter>
                <type>app-adapter</type>
                <code>IC</code>
                <name>te</name>
                <property name="hasAttachment" value="false"/>
            </adapter>
            <mep>push-sync</mep>
            <outbound name="outbound_9">
                <binding>rest</binding>
                <operation>execute</operation>
                <resourceGroup name="resourcegroup_10">
                    <resource name="resource_11" location="../resources/application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/te_REQUEST.jca" type="jca"/>
                    <resource name="resource_12" location="../resources/application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/te_REQUEST.wsdl" type="wsdl"/>
                </resourceGroup>
                <input name="input_14">
                    <role>response</role>
                    <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_13"/>
                </input>
                <input name="input_18">
                    <role>fault</role>
                    <subRole>APIInvocationError</subRole>
                    <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_17"/>
                </input>
                <output name="output_16">
                    <role>request</role>
                    <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_15"/>
                </output>
            </outbound>
        </application>
        <processor name="processor_1">
            <type>messageTracker</type>
            <role>messageTracker:global</role>
            <trackingVariableGroup>
                <trackingVariable>
                    <role>tracking_var_1</role>
                    <primary>true</primary>
                    <name>tracking_var_1</name>
                    <output name="output_3">
                        <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_2"/>
                    </output>
                </trackingVariable>
                <trackingVariable>
                    <role>tracking_var_2</role>
                    <primary>false</primary>
                    <name>tracking_var_2</name>
                    <output name="output_5">
                        <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_4"/>
                    </output>
                </trackingVariable>
                <trackingVariable>
                    <role>tracking_var_3</role>
                    <primary>false</primary>
                    <name>tracking_var_3</name>
                    <output name="output_7">
                        <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_6"/>
                    </output>
                </trackingVariable>
            </trackingVariableGroup>
        </processor>
        <processor name="processor_19">
            <type>transformer</type>
            <role>transformer:response-map</role>
            <resourceGroup name="resourcegroup_22">
                <resource name="resource_23" location="../resources/processor_19/resourcegroup_22/req_de8ec82b6bfb42da9111bce9ee4ba445.xsl" type="xslt"/>
            </resourceGroup>
            <input name="input_20">
                <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_15"/>
            </input>
            <output name="output_21">
                <messageContextRef refUri="messagecontext_13"/>
            </output>
            <property name="has-mappings" value="false"/>
        </processor>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_2">
            <rootElement elementName="string" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </messageContext>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_4">
            <rootElement elementName="string" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </messageContext>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_6">
            <rootElement elementName="string" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </messageContext>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_13">
            <resourceRef refUri="application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/resource_12"/>
            <rootElement elementName="executeResponse" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST/types"/>
            <wsdlMessage messageName="executeResponseMessage" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST" partName="parameters"/>
        </messageContext>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_15">
            <resourceRef refUri="application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/resource_12"/>
            <rootElement elementName="execute" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST/types"/>
            <wsdlMessage messageName="executeRequestMessage" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST" partName="parameters"/>
        </messageContext>
        <messageContext name="messagecontext_17">
            <resourceRef refUri="application_8/outbound_9/resourcegroup_10/resource_12"/>
            <rootElement elementName="APIInvocationError" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/te"/>
            <wsdlMessage messageName="APIInvocationError" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST" partName="parameters"/>
            <wsdlFault faultName="APIInvocationError" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/te_REQUEST"/>
        </messageContext>
        <commonNamespaceMaps/>
        <orchestration>
            <receive id="r0" refUri="application_8/outbound_9/output_16" trackingRefUri="processor_1"/>
            <transformer id="m0" refUri="processor_19"/>
            <reply id="y0" refUri="application_8/outbound_9/input_14"/>
        </orchestration>
    </ns1:icsflow>
</ns1:icsproject>
```

Your file will have a similar structure but value-wise will look nothing like mine.  All you need to do is find the `<name>` element nested within the `<adapter>` element.  For you the value should read *AccountCreateEvent*.  Change that value to whatever you wish your new name to be.

Repackage your `iar` file to include the new *project.xml* file.  Go back into your Integration Cloud design console and download a the integration again (as a backup), and then delete it.  Now import the update integration. Open the integration and your app adapter will now display the updated name.

#### 2. JDeveloper and OSB

Oracle's Integration Cloud Service is really just a simplified, cloud-base adaptation of *Oracle Service Bus* (abbreviated *OSB*).  OSB is the integration component of Oracle SOA (a suite of applications which make up a full service oriented platform).  ICS runs on an Oracle Linux VM that runs OSB.  Your integrations are actually just OSB composites and actually run on OSB (which is fully installed on the VM that runs ICS).  If you want proof, navigate to https://your-instance-name:443/soa-infra and you will see your integration listed as an SOA composite.

If you are up-to-date your ICS underline runtime is SOA 12c (probably 12.2.1). If you really want to become familiar with the ICS platform I suggest you download the [Oracle SOA Suite for 12c](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/soasuite1221-quickstartdownload-3050431.html) (an IDE based on JDeveloper with all the SOA plugins pre-installed).  Then inside ICS find and integration and *Download Artifacts* (not export).

Install JDeveloper (it will take hours) then open JDeveloper and create a new *Oracle Service Bus Application with Service Bus Project*

[image: OSB]

Import a new Service Bus Resource

[image: OSB Resource]

Choose Resource/zip then locate your zip artifact.

[image: artifact]

Your project will now look like this

[image: SOA project]

You have now turned your ICS Integration into an SOA composite!  You could make the same edits here, but more importantly it will allow you to inspect the underline structure, see how it fits with OSB/SOA, etc.  ICS is a great tool for simple projects, but if you need to do more complex things you are absolutely going to need to understand the underline SOA runtime and take advantage of it to extend the functionality not present on the ICS/OIC web interface.

As a side note, this can also be done with Process Cloud by exporting an application as an `exp` and importing it as a BPM project.